# How to bring 2 texts together in css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

Relatively new to CSS and I don't know how to word this to google. How would I bring the two texts together so that "Press Any Key to Continue" is right on top of it, but still aligned.[image: 2 Texts far apart]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
        <title>Ameglass</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Press Any Key to Continue</p>
            <h1 class="gradient-text" style="font-size:400%">Welcome to Ameglass</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #EE82EE 30%, #00D1FF 100%);
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh
}

.gradient-text {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #d173d1 33%,#9460e7 66%, #00D1FF 100%);
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
}
```

I'm not sure what to change here.

If you can tell how to do so, I would be very grateful,
Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to reduce the distance between the two lines of text?

Answer (score 1):

Headings and paragraphs (like a lot of elements) have default margins set by the browser. It sounds like you just want to reduce those default margins with something like `h1, p {margin: 0;}`:

```css
h1, p {margin: 0;}
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #EE82EE 30%, #00D1FF 100%);
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh
}

.gradient-text {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #d173d1 33%,#9460e7 66%, #00D1FF 100%);
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Press Any Key to Continue</p>
  <h1 class="gradient-text" style="font-size:400%">Welcome to Ameglass</h1>
</div>
```